# using java.nio.file adding the arraylist to the file

Tags: java

What method can be used to add arraylist to the file using  java.nio.file ?

Previously I could be using

```
     List<String> outputData = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     //Output arraylist containing concatenated data

     writeLines(File outputFile,outputData); //The data is written to file
```

now if i want to utilize nio library what do i do?

```
   Path outputFile= Paths.get("outputFile");
   List<String> outputData = new ArrayList<String>(); 
   //???How to put the list in the file?
```

Comment: `java.nio.channel.FileChannel` and its static `open(Path p, OpenOption... o)` seems to be what you're looking for, but I hope you know why you want to switch to `java.nio`.

Comment: Start by reading the [java.nio.file.Files documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).